# ObservableCollection vs List for fixed number of items in Windows Phone

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, list, data-binding, observablecollection

In my Windows Phone app all collections bound to the views are ObservableCollections.

Everytime I reload the data, I clear these ObservableCollections, load the new data in lists (it's a fixed amount of items) then I add those items to the ObservableCollections (in a loop, since ObservableCollections don't have the AddRange method).

Then I started thinking, since I am clearing the items in the collections and adding new ones with a fixed amount: Would it be faster for the UI to bind the lists directly to the DataSource of the controls?

Note that as I said before I never increment data to the collections. I clear them and add the new items.

Comment: Why load data in list first and then transfer to OC? Load in OC directly.

Comment: I load the data in another thread using the background worker, that's why I load it in a list, to pass it back to the UI Thread. So you're saying that I should load the data to the ObservableCollection in the BackgroundWorker and just do a uiCollection = bwCollection?